# VerifyError Eclipse "warning: method is huge"

Tags: android, eclipse, verifyerror

I'm running a program in Eclipse that involves doing a bit of math and database inputting. At one point it seems to be too much because Eclipse gives me a VerifyError. When I delete a little bit it runs fine, doesn't matter what I delete so it's not a specific part causing the error but the length of it all, it seems. Here's the error message:

```
10-27 17:04:03.855: W/dalvikvm(12618): VFY: warning: method is huge (regs=643 insnsSize=7090)
10-27 17:04:03.855: W/dalvikvm(12618): VFY:  rejected Lcom/example/simpledatabasetutorial/DatabaseManageActivity;.onClick (Landroid/view/View;)V
10-27 17:04:04.114: W/dalvikvm(12618): VFY: register2 v12-13 values 0,0
10-27 17:04:04.114: W/dalvikvm(12618): VFY:  rejecting opcode 0xab at 0x10f2
10-27 17:04:04.114: W/dalvikvm(12618): VFY:  rejected Lcom/example/simpledatabasetutorial/DatabaseManageActivity;.onClick (Landroid/view/View;)V
10-27 17:04:04.114: W/dalvikvm(12618): Verifier rejected class Lcom/example/simpledatabasetutorial/DatabaseManageActivity;
10-27 17:04:04.114: W/dalvikvm(12618): Class init failed in newInstance call (Lcom/example/simpledatabasetutorial/DatabaseManageActivity;)
10-27 17:04:04.114: D/AndroidRuntime(12618): Shutting down VM
10-27 17:04:04.114: W/dalvikvm(12618): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40015560)
10-27 17:04:04.145: E/AndroidRuntime(12618): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
10-27 17:04:04.145: E/AndroidRuntime(12618): java.lang.VerifyError: com.example.simpledatabasetutorial.DatabaseManageActivity
```

Any ideas of a quick solution? Maybe this is far from enough info, if that's the case just let me know and I'll include what ever is relevant.

Comment: The first error means [your method is too large](http://stackoverflow.com/q/4748771/60462) (in terms of code), which you could have found by just looking around. No idea about the 2nd error.

Comment: Have you tried breaking the method up into multiple, smaller methods?  Or perhaps encapsulating the code inside the method into multiple methods?

Comment: My next step is dividing my code into smaller methods, hopefully that will take care of the problem. I'll keep you posted

Answer (score 1):

The problem isn't actually that your method is too large.  As of gingerbread, excessively-large methods no longer cause the method to be rejected.  (The first "rejected" message just appears because it's using the `LOG_VFY_METH` macro to report the method name.)

The real problem is the second complaint, `register2 v12-13 values 0,0 ... rejecting opcode 0xab`.  0xab is an "add-double" instruction, which takes a 64-bit argument, which means the types on the two 32-bit Dalvik registers should be "double low" and "double high".  The verifier found that they're both type zero, which is "unknown".

So either there's a bug in the Dalvik verifier or there's a bug in the generated code (possibly originating in the "dx" tool).  You should file a report on http://b.android.com/.